# Why is cors used inside socket.io?

Tags: socket.io, cors

It seems that cors middleware is a prerequisite when it comes to using socketio chat application. 
but honestly, I cannot understand the reason why we use cors.

```
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
```

My server is running on localhost:3000, and that io is relying on my server. So domains of both are same with localhost:3000. But why is cors needed?
Some explanation might be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your socket.io server is the same host and port as the web server that the containing web page came from, then you do not need CORs at all.

CORs is only needed when you need to make an http request to a different domain or port.  Further, if you limit socket.io to ONLY use the webSocket transport and not do it's little initialization routine that starts out with http polling, then you don't even need CORS to do cross origin socket.io.

So, to summarize, socket.io needs CORs only when your socket.io server is a different host or port than the web page that the connection is being made from and you can avoid CORs even then if you turn off the http polling transport so that socket.io only uses a webSocket as the transport.

Comment: really appreciate for your detailed-explanation.

I have one more question if you do not mind..

A lot of socket io examples recommend us to put cors middleware when using socketio.
but as you mentioned, that applies to the situation only when socket io host and server host are different from each other.

is there any reason I have to  seperate socket io host and my server host?

Comment: @jwkoo - If your architecture isn't driving you to separate your socket.io server from your web server, then there is no reason to separate them.  webSocket (which is the transport for socket.io) was explicitly designed to be able to share the web server and it works just fine doing that.  The only main reason I know of to split them might be for scaling reasons, but there are probably many things I'd first to improve scale.

Comment: appreciate that. since I do not have any concepts of scaling..(I am novice.), is there any advantages from scaling, to seperate socket io server and host server? the reason for this question is because I thought that single-server will be more faster than two server. If I have two servers, the http transaction might be doubled.. though maybe it`s just a wrong guess..

Comment: @jwkoo - There's no doubling of http transactions if you scale and split into two servers.  There may be extra work/overhead involved when you have to share state between server processes since it can't be simple shared memory like it is when both servers are in the same node.js process.  It's a longer conversation about large scale, but it's not uncommon to break your server process up into smaller pieces when going to large scale.  That's nothing specific to socket.io, it's just one thing that could be split out to give you some different scaling options.

Comment: @jwkoo - Since I subscribe to the axiom that your code should be no more complicated than it needs to be, I'd say you should stay in one node.js process until you find a compelling reason to break something out into a second server.  In other words, "keep it simple" until simple won't do.

Comment: your answer is magic. though my English was not good enough, you`ve catched perfectly what i was curious about. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does not support CORS requests on localhost, [and there's a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743) regarding this issue which has been marked as a WontFix. They suggest you to use [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) to temporarily disable CORS during development. So rather than having a CORS middleware on socket.io, which you may forget to remove in production, you can use the chrome extension for localhost testing.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I did not know that. but what if it was not just the case of localhost? why I need cors middleware? assuming that my domain is www.something.com and socket io relies on something.com. domains are same but why i need cors?

Comment: You do not need CORS if you are communicating on the same domain. In fact, if you disable HTTP long polling in socket.io and force use of websockets, you won't need CORS for even cross-domain communication. Check @jfriend00 's answer